# Visual trace of sorting algorithms using a graph in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, graph, plot

I am in an Intro to data structures class and we are currently going over sorting algorithms. Is there any way in C++ to use a graph to trace the exchanging and sorting of sorting algorithms? There is an image illustrating shell sort if you follow this link and scroll down a bit. I also linked it down below. (Essentially what I would like to achieve). Addison Wesley, Algorithms 4th edition: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/21elementary/.

They spoke about using built in functions in Java to create the graph and spoke about it as if it is rather trivial. I'm assuming if its basic in Java its basic in C++.

Question being, how would I implement a function that would correspond numerically to how big the bars are and output the graph pre-sort, mid-sort and post-sort?

Note: I have intermediate level C++ knowledge and no experience with graphics.

[image]

Comment: Neither Java nor C++ have graph libraries by default, though it's trivial with a library in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a graphing package such as [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/links.html). You would have to use it to plot, say as bar graphs, the array values your program is trying to sort.

Comment: I think a nice option would be to dump raw data from your C++ code and then display it with some scripting language. Python comes to mind (there are many plotting libraries) or even more specialized tools like Matlab. That way you can reuse your plotting routines for other languages too.